# how to unpublish a comment rather than deleting it

Tags: 7, comments

I like to use "threaded style" comments. However the problem with them is that when a users deletes their own comments all the "replies" to those comments are deleted as well.

Is there a way to "unpublish" those comments instead of deleting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To unpublish a comment, click on the link to edit it. In the page that appears, you will see an "Administration" section that is a a collapsed field set; select the "Non published" checkbox, and the comment will be unpublished.

[image: screenshot]

If you unpublish a comment, the child comments will still be published; you need to unpublish each of them.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I think by unpublishing the comment you will get the same result. Replies not appearing.

You could use the flag module to provide a 'delete link' flag and then remove the default delete link. You could then at the template level detect whether the comment author has decided they want to delete the comment (i.e. flagged it) and show a message such as "Author removed comment" etc. That way they would still appear in a threaded list.

Comment: that's a good workaround. I just did a test and checked the database. When I set the status for the first threaded comment to 0 (unpublished) it will not show but replies to it will show. For the admin it will show the thread in red and adds an "approve" link.  When I use the "delete" link it deletes the both comments from the table. How can I add a "unpublish" or "unapprove" link to comments?

Answer (score 1):

With http://drupal.org/project/hidden_comment you can hide a comment without having to give the "administer comment" permission to a role. Even more, you can allow a role to hide comments in their posts.